# Scheme Program that returns

Tags: lisp, scheme

IS this the correct reverse method is i would like to create a 'oddrev' function that does as such from the following list:

```
(DEFINE list0 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j) )
(DEFINE list1 (LIST 'a 'b 'c 'd 'e 'f 'g) )
(DEFINE list2 (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z) )
(DEFINE list3 (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'l 'k 'j) )
(DEFINE list4 (LIST 'n 'o 'p 'q 'q 'p 'o 'n) )
(DEFINE list5 '( (a b) c (d e d) c (a b) ) )
(DEFINE list6 '( (h i) (j k) l (m n) ) )
(DEFINE list7 (f (a b) c (d e d) (b a) f) )
```

`(oddrev '(a b c d e f g))`
which would/should return:
`(g e c a)`

`(oddrev (LIST 's 't 'u 'v 'w 'x 'y 'z))`
which would/should return:
`(y w u s)`

`(oddrev '((h i) (j k) l (m n)))`
which would/should return:
`(l (h i))`

and

`(oddrev '())`
which would/should return a empty list, etc.

**Does this code look correct and how can i incorporate the reverse command into it:**

```
(define mylist '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
(define (oddrev lst)
(define (do-oddrev lst odd)
    (if (null? lst)
        lst
    (if even
        (do-oddrev (cdr lst) #f)
        (reverse (cons (car lst) (do-oddrev (cdr lst) #t))))))
        (do-evens lst #f))
```

or should can i do something as such:

```
(define (oddrev 1st)
    (if (NULL? 1st) '()
        (append (reverse (cdr 1st)) (list (car 1st)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to build an (odd *lis*) procedure that will get the odd elements of a list, then make an (oddrev *lis*) procedure that calls the odd procedure, and applies the reverse procedure to it's results.

The odd procedure should look like this:

```
    (define (odd lis)
      (if (null? lis)
          '()
          (if (= (length lis) 1)
              (list (car lis))
              (cons (car lis) (odd (cddr lis))))))
```

Given that, we must now define oddrev. This part is easy, just call odd, then reverse it, like so:

```
    (define (oddrev lis)
      (reverse (odd lis))
```

I tested this in DrRacket 5.3 to make sure it worked, and the results conformed perfectly with the specifications outlined in your question. If you have any issues with the code, let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much, glad to know that I'm getting somewhat close to the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (oddrev L)
 (oddrev-helper L '()))

 (define (oddrev-helper L-in L-out)
  (cond 
   ((null? L-in) L-out)
   ((null? (cdr L-in)) (cons (car L-in) L-out))
   (else (oddrev-helper (cddr l-in) (cons (car L-in) L-out)))))
```

Using append recursively usually is a good signal that there's a better way to do it, often by calling a helper with a null list as an additional argument and building your list on top of that.